# Retrieve color from matplotlib perceptually uniform scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to retrieve the color values from the 'perceptually uniform' color maps in matplotlib listed [in the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). It seems like for all other colormaps the `cmap()` function seems to work, but for the perceptually uniform ones (for example 'plasma') it unfortunately does not. Is there an alternate way to retrieve such values?

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('gist_ncar')
print cmap( 0.5 )

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('plasma')
print cmap( 0.5 )
```

gives

```
>>> (0.85737517232758309, 1.0, 0.12482388288648784, 1.0)
>>> ValueError: Colormap plasma is not recognized...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that `plasma` doesn't work like that (it does), its that `plasma` is not available in your version of `matplotlib`.

I suspect if you print the version number (`matplotlib.__version__`) you will get something less than `1.5`

Try updating to the latest version (`1.5.1`)